# configure syslog in Docker to write container logs into a file

Tags: docker

I try to use syslog as driver to collect logs 
using following command:

```
docker run --log-driver syslog --log-opt syslog-address=udp://localhost:514 --log-opt tag=expconf  app-1
```

Where does the syslog write this log?

I want the logs to be written into a specific file/ location. How to achieve this?

Comment: See if this helps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96484/how-can-i-configure-syslog-conf-file-to-log-iptables-messages-in-a-separate-fil

Comment: I do not have syslog.conf file at /etc/syslog.conf

Comment: check if which service is running for you? syslog or rsyslog

Comment: How to configure the syslog to write into specific file.

Comment: See this https://www.soundtraining.net/i-t-tutorials/linux-tutorials/34-configuring-syslogd

Comment: It has rsyslog is running.

Comment: See if this helps. http://chrishood.typepad.com/blog/2008/12/using-rsyslog-to-split-syslog-feeds-into-multiple-files.html. I am not an expert in rsyslog so will only be able to point you into a direction

Comment: I have added *.* /var/log1/agentlogs
line in the /etc/rsyslog.conf  file and then did service restart. Still it is not writing to this new file, agentlogs.